# How to set check box checked by comparing the database value in struts1.3?

Tags: jsp, struts

In my Struts1.3 application, I have a Jsp page where i have a hyperlink on clicking of that hyperlink i am showing all the records that is coming from database in checkbooks mycode is to showing all the values are as follows

```
<table width="932" border="1" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#E9E9E9">
    <%for (int i = 0; i < landlordList.size(); i++) {%>
    <tr>
        <td width="50" align="left">
            <table width="30" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td width="20"><label>
                        <html:checkbox value="<%=landlordList.get(i).getLandlordId()%>" property="landlordId"
                                       name="ExporterForm" styleId="landlordId"/>
                    </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td class="landlord_name"><%=landlordList.get(i).getLandlordname()%></td>
    </tr>
    <%}%>
</table>
```

and `property="landlordId"` is defined as a `String[]` in my action class. And i have one more `list2` which contain few records my query is. How can i compare the list2 with `landlordList` if `landlordList` conatains any record of `list2`  then mark corresponding to these records as `checked`. please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution by using `multibox`

```
<logic:iterate name="<%=Constant.LANDLORDLIST%>" id="customer">
<tr>
<td width="50" align="left"><table width="30" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="20">
<label>
<html:multibox property="landlordid" name="ExporterForm">
<bean:write name="customer" property="value" />
</html:multibox>
</label>
/td>
</tr>
</table></td>
<td class="landlord_name"><bean:write name="customer" property="label" /></td>
</tr>
</logic:iterate>
```

Comment: By using multibox and logic Iterate, I am able to solve this.